# Setting value of a radio button into a text input

Tags: javascript, html

I have to do 5 radio button and each of them have the value 10,15,20,25,30

(so the first radio is 10, the second 15, etc )

If I click on the radio button, the value should be showed in a text input. I am really not sure how to do this. One thing, I really need to stay with java and html...heh. Also, my teacher is asking me to use the object 'this' ( and I never worked with the object 'this' ) Here's my codes, thanks! :

Java :

```
(function(){

var oForm = document.forms;

oForm[0].querySelector("input[type='radio']").
                                    addEventListener("click",
                                                                    sommeButton,
                                                                    false);

}) ()

function sommeButton () {

var aButton = document.forms[0].r1;

}
```

and html :

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Exercise 5</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/form.css" />
</head>
<body>
                <section>
            <form name="frm1">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" 
                    value="1" 
                    name="r1" />
                </label>

                <label>
                    <input type="radio" 
                    value="2" 
                    name="r1" />
                </label>

                <label>
                    <input type="radio" 
                    value="3" 
                    name="r1" />
                </label>

                <label>
                    <input type="radio" 
                    value="4" 
                    name="r1" />
                </label>

                <label>
                    <input type="radio" 
                    value="5" 
                    name="r1" />
                </label>

                <label>
                    <input type="text" name="tEx2" />
                </label>
            </form>
        </section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you expect someone to do your school assignment rather than doing some research and learning? What if your teacher asks you questions about your work/assignment...

Comment: I am truly trying to understand but I can't make up with the fact that I have to use 'this' when he never spoke about it. This whole thing is clearly not understandable for me...

Comment: Please take some time to read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this I can see someone has carelessly answered without explaining anything about `this` which is obviously the issue. If you just copy/paste and don't learn from it then you might shoot yourself in the foot for your next assignment as it might be to expand on the current one which you might not know how to do due to not understanding the source code. I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: thank you for the link. As I read for the object this, maybe you can answer me just a small question. In the problem, this is supposed to return for the value of each radio, am I correct or I didn't understood the point of 'this' ?

Comment: I will try explain it as short but in detail. `input[type='radio']` is used in a selector for all radio buttons on that page. An event listener is then attached to all items/radio buttons. This will execute/call a function when that event becomes true, in this case `click` you click on the radio button a function is called due to a click event taking place. `this` carries information from whatever has triggered the call/function so `this.value` will be `this` > the element clicked/used to trigger the function `.value` > the value of `this` which will be the value of the clicked radio.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you very much, it helped me alot and finaly manage to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

This code example will walk you through exactly what you are asking.  It will cover each of the topics that your question deals with including:

- Collecting elements in a document
- Attaching event listeners
- Use of `this` in a scope
- Getting and setting the the value of `<input>` element

A detailed explanation of each topic is included as a comment next to the appropriate code below.

```js
/*jslint browser:true*/

(function(doc) {
  "use strict";

  // This will be all of our logic for our program
  function main() {
    // Define our vars
    var output, radios;

    /*
     * Now we need to collect the elements that we are going use
     * We do that with documnet.getElementById() if the element
     * has an id attribute that we know of.  We can also use
     * the querySelecter family to find elements with explicit
     * ids.  For example, we are going to look for all inputs whose
     * type property is "radio", that means we get all the
     * radio inputs in the document.
     */

    // Find the input named "output" in our document
    output = doc.getElementById("output");
    // Get the radio inputs in our document
    radios = doc.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");

    // This function will set the value of the output element
    function printValue() {

      /*
       * An important thing to note is that you have access to
       * "output" here.  The output variable was captured and is
       * available in this funciton's scope.
       *
       * The other thing is that the "this" variable, in this
       * instance, will be set to the radio button that the
       * change event listener is attached to.
       */

      // Make sure that this is the "checked" radio button
      if (this.checked) {
        // Set the "output" input's value to this radio's value
        output.value = this.value;
      }
    }

    // This is just a functor to use with the Array.prototype.forEach()
    function setupRadio(radio) {

      /*
       * Here we actually attach the change event listener
       * That means that whenever the radio changes, it will call
       * the function that we attached.
       *
       * The nice thing about addEventListener() is that whenever
       * it calls your function, it sets the scope to whatever the
       * listener was attached to.
       *
       * In other words, it calls "printValue" and sets the "this"
       * variable to radio.  because of that, you have access to
       * all of radio's properties without having to explicitly
       * pass the radio to the printValue function.
       */

      // Attach the change listener
      radio.addEventListener("change", printValue);
    }

    /*
     * NodeLists don't have a forEach method, so we borrow Array's
     * This lets us iterate over all of the radios that we selected
     * and call "setupRadio" on each one.
     */
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(radios, setupRadio);
  }

  // Here we wait for the document to finish loading then call the "main" function
  doc.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", main);
}(document));
```

```css
main {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <label for="output">Current Radio Value</label>
  <input id="output" type="text">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Radio Choices</legend>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="which" value="First">
          <span>First</span>
        </label>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>
          <input type="radio" name="which" value="Second">
          <span>Second</span>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</main>
```